# How can I change the current position of UIPageControl according to the CollectionViewCell's item

Tags: ios, swift2, uicollectionviewcell, uipagecontrol

my View hierarchy is something like:

`TableView-->tableViewCell-->CollectionView-->CollectionViewCell-->imageView`

and in my tableViewCell I have some other items (textView, labels and  a UIPageControl) so now am trying to change the currentPage of PageControl according to the item of CollectionViewCell ( same as carousel ) but I don't know why UIPageControl is not changing its position this is what I tried:

```
override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    // here scrollView is my collectionView 
    if scrollView != tableView {
        pagerControll.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / self.view.frame.size.width)
    }
}
```

I also tried this (for remembering the current position of Item in a cell after scrolling through the tableView)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                        willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
                                        forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    guard let cell = cell as? NotesTableViewCell else { return }

    cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)

    cell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[indexPath.row] ?? 0 
        cell.pageControll.currentPage = calculateCurrentPage(storedOffsets[indexPath.row]  ?? 0)

}
```

above am fetching  the contentOffset of each Row from an array of (contentoffset)   so that I can show the previous positions Of  CollectionViewCell's items, when tableView reuses the cell  its working fine for the items of my collectionView cell but not for my `UIPageControl`

```
func calculateCurrentPage(offSet : CGFloat) -> Int{

    if offSet >= self.view.frame.size.width && offSet < (self.view.frame.size.width*2) {

        return 1

    }else if offSet >= (self.view.frame.size.width*2)  {

        return 2

    }else {

        return 0
    }
}
```

What's wrong here? or how to do it?

UPDate Extra Codes:

//inside my tableViewCell
        func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate
        >
        (dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

```
    collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.tag = row
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

//in TableView

```
extension NotesTableViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        pagerControll.numberOfPages = attachedImgUrlDict[collectionView.tag]!.count
        return attachedImgUrlDict[collectionView.tag]!.count
    }



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let newSize = CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width  , collectionView.frame.size.height)

        return newSize
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        //t,l,b,r
    }

    override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if scrollView != tableView {

            if scrollView.contentOffset.x >= 320 && scrollView.contentOffset.x < 640{

                 pagerControll.currentPage = 1
            }else if  scrollView.contentOffset.x >= 600 {

            pagerControll.currentPage = 2

            }
            //pagerControll.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / self.view.frame.size.width)

            print(scrollView.contentOffset)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Check #1

You'll receive callbacks for scroll events for `UICollectionView` as soon as you set a `UICollectionViewDelegate` on the `collectionView` instance.

Seems like you might be missing setting up `UICollectionViewDelegate` in following call

```
cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
```

Can you verify you're receiving callbacks for `UICollectionView` scroll events?

#### Check #2

Say you are receiving callbacks properly now, Can you check your logic works properly with page index? A good thing would be to add a print statement that would show you the page index that you are calculating.

```
let pageIndex = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / self.view.frame.size.width)
print("pageIndex == \(pageIndex)")
```

#### Check #3

Say you are calculating it right, Can you check if `cell.pageControl` is populated with properly with `UIPageControl` instance you need to update.

Maybe you need to check your `IBOutlet` connections?

#### Check #4

Inside `prepareForReuse()` callback, you need to make sure that `pageControl` is set to some initial value like 0.

Adding a small delay while updating the `pageIndex` could work if you see inconsistencies like it is updating sometimes and sometimes it's not.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes i do because thats how am changing my images from the imageView , btw how am gonna show you ?

Comment: @remyboys `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` are two different things. Are you sure you have set up both? Please share the code inside **setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate()** method.

Comment: Please see the Updated question @TarunTyagi

Comment: hey man i checked it and there's a strange thing happening , when the table is loading for the first time and i change my image the PageControl.currentpage is not changing but when i scroll down to bottom and then scroll to top and changing my image then everything is working fine  , know why is it happening ? seems like something related to TableView lifeCycle

Comment: @remyboys Well, that's a first! Maybe you could check if the `pageControl` is loaded properly when cells are being prepared for reuse inside `override  prepareForReuse` callback. Or Adding a small delay like 0.01 - 0.1 seconds could work when you update the `pageIndex` Seems like an inconsistency in timing of the logic being applied. Just updated the answer. Have a look at Check #4.

Comment: thanks for your effort man , appreciate you , did the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883572/issue-while-changing-the-currentpage-of-uipagecontrol-which-is-inside-a-tablevie