# issue while changing the CurrentPage of UIPageControl which is Inside a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

am trying to create a Carousel inside tableViewCell and am almost there but am having difficulty while implementing the UIPageControl in my TableView so that when CollectionViewCell's (which is inside tableViewCell) Item got changed i can show it on UIPageControl,

i tried the below solution  and encountered a strange behaviour (maybe its strange for only me )  ,  when the View Loads and i change my `item` (which is in collectionViewCell) the PageControl's currentPage is not changing but after   scrolling  down to the end of tableView and coming  back to top  its working fine ,

suppose you have 6 rows and you scroll down to row 6 and then when you scroll up to row 5 and change its item the pageControl will work , if you keep doing this until reaching the top it'll going to work fine but if you go from row 5 to 6 and change row 6's item then its not going to work

i am initialising my `pageControl` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
  pagerControll = cell.pageControll
```

then trying to change the position by listening  to ScrollView's contentOffSet

```
override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

if scrollView != tableView {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.x >= self.view.frame.size.width && scrollView.contentOffset.x < (self.view.frame.size.width * 2){

        pagerControll.currentPage = 1
    }else if  scrollView.contentOffset.x >= (self.view.frame.size.width * 2 )  {
        pagerControll.currentPage = 2

    }else {

        pagerControll.currentPage = 0
    }

    print(scrollView.contentOffset) }
}
```

any idea why this is happening ?? or how to fix this ??

P.s if question is not clear enough then let me know , i'll add some more detail

UPDATE:

when view loads and am changing the item of collectionViewCell the below cell's pageControl's currentPage is Changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after getting pissed off , WE MADE IT

```
    override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if scrollView != tableView {

           let currentCells =  tableView.visibleCells
            let cell = currentCells[0] as! NotesTableViewCell

            if scrollView.contentOffset.x >= self.view.frame.size.width && scrollView.contentOffset.x < (self.view.frame.size.width * 2){

                cell.pageControll.currentPage = 1
            }else if  scrollView.contentOffset.x >= (self.view.frame.size.width * 2 )  {

                cell.pageControll.currentPage = 2

            }else {

                cell.pageControll.currentPage = 0
            }
        }

    }
```

[image]